# A "functional" central limit theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, soft-question

It is known that if $X_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$, are i.i.d random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$, then $\frac {1} {\sqrt n} (X_1+ \dots+X_n)$ converges in distribution to a $\mathcal N(0,1)$ (CLT).

What if we have $\{ X_t : t \in [0,n]\}$ i.i.d random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$ ? Is there a similar result to the classical CLT for the asymptotic distribution of

$$\frac {1} {\sqrt n} \int_0^nX_t \, dt$$

This is a soft question as I am not sure if what I am asking makes sense.

Comment: What makes you think $X_t$ (with $t$ in an uncountable set) is integrable?  What might $\int_0^1X_t \, dt$ be?

Comment: because $\sup_{t \in [0,n]} X_t < \infty $ at fixed $\omega$ ? So it is integrable at fixed $\omega$. For example $\int_0^1 X_t dt$ is the random variable that gives you the area under the path $X_t$ between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Henry 's comment is well taken.  There is Donsker's theorem, a.k.a. "functional central limit theorem" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem) but it is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: $X_t$ is not really a path.  I suspect you are are imagining the integral is something like a standard [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) but that is not differentiable

Comment: Even the measurability of sample paths $t\mapsto X_t$ seems a serious issue to me. This is similar to the situation where the path-regularity of the Brownian motion $B=(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is not measurable information if $B$ is merely treated as stochastic process in $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$. As far as I remember, the closest thing is a *white noise*, which is often realized as random functional on a suitable Hilbert space, but I am no expert on this topic.

Comment: You can add any hypothesis on the process $X_t$. My question is more about "is there literature on something like that". Basically literature on the asymptotic distribution of the rescaled area under a stochastic process, which happens to be "CLT" in continuous times.

Comment: I guess then you are more interested in the keyword 'functional CLT', which deals with the CLT for sample paths. A classical example comes from classical CLT, where the stochastic process $X^{(n)}=(X^{(n)}_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ given by $$X^{(n)}_t:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k\leq nt} X_{k}$$ converges to the Brownian motion $B=(B_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ in suitable sense. This in particular shows that $$\int_{0}^{1} X^{(n)}_s \, \mathrm{d}s \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{\text{law}} \int_{0}^{1} B_s\,\mathrm{d}s$$ and likewise for other nice funtionals on sample paths.